# If condition in which (>,<,=) these are come from database

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

hi i have there value which come from database, i have enter (<,>) these value from user end and give condition according to user, but i have face problem to do it, my if condition is not run properly .

```
<?php
$sql_land = "SELECT * FROM condition_check;
//echo $sql;    

in above assume value are come
$sum = 50;
$green_cond = >;
$Green_val = 30

now i want give if condition
if($sum $green_cond $Green_val )  // these are equal to if($sum > $Green_val)
{
echo "true"
}
else
{
echo "false";
}


}
?>
```

// can it is possible to give (<,>,=) with variable $green_cond
    i face problem in these , can anybody help me

Comment: i try  <?php
     $val = 50;
     $val1 =80;
     $cond = '>';
     echo $cond;
     echo '<br>';
     if($val .$cond .$val1)
     {
      echo "true";
     }
     else
     {
      echo "false";
     }
      if($val > $val1)
     {
      echo "true";
     }
     else
     {
      echo "false";
     }
     
     ?>

Comment: Would yo please check my answer?

Comment: What you want to achieve is to have your comparison operator in a variable instead of typing it?

Answer (score 0):

You do it by the following code...
**It is possible to give (<,>,=) with variable, Using following code..**

```
<?php

function lt($a, $b) {
    if ($a < $b) {
        return "B is grater then A";
    } else {
        return "A is grater then B";
    }
}
$relops = Array(
    '<' => 'lt',
);
echo $relops['<'](50, 30);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a PHP function which does exactly that, its purpose is to compare versions but it should work for you.

You pass your numbers as the 2 first arguments, and the operator as the third.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php